# Symbol for home,delete,download,documents in java

Tags: java, ms-word, awt

[image: Image is showing symbols for each action]During Java project I got stuck at one point where i want to use symbols for

`download option,document option,trash option,recent option,picture option,music option and add other location option`

as presented in NOTEPAD but i don't know how to fetch their symbols in java to print on console or on any frame object.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't print them on the console - consoles only print characters and not images.

Comment: The top symbol in that image is difficult to see.  If you must provide a screen shot, please use your Print Screen key instead of taking a photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use icons from materialdesignicons.com.

Comment: Is there any package to be installed it in java software or can be done only by downloading image from aforementioned site.

Comment: Download image and load it via java.

Answer (score 2):

Those are images (probably in SVG format), not characters.  However, you can come pretty close with various Unicode characters:

```
Downloads:       "\u21e3"       U+21E3 DOWNWARDS DASHED ARROW “⇣”
Documents:       "\ud83d\uddcb" U+1F5CB EMPTY DOCUMENT “”
Trash:           "\ud83d\uddd1" U+1F5D1 WASTEBASKET “”
Recent:          "\ud83d\udd72" U+1F559 CLOCK FACE TEN OCLOCK “”
Pictures:        "\ud83d\udcf7" U+1F4F7 CAMERA “”
Music:           "\u266b"       U+266B BEAMED EIGHTH NOTES “♫”
Other Locations: "\u2795"       U+2795 HEAVY PLUS SIGN “➕”
```